# Определить - содержится ли строка s1 в строке s2 ровно N раз

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Как с помощью регулярных выражений определить - содержит ли заданная строка `s1` заданную строку `s2` ровно N раз? Например: определить с помощью регулярных выражений содержит ли строка `"abcdaa"` строку `"a"` ровно три раза.

*P.S. Понимаю, что задача решается и без регулярных выражений, но мне необходимо решить её именно с ними.*

Comment: А как вы уже пробовали решить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто, это сделать. Попробуйте следующий раз самостоятельно решить эту проблему

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher("abcdaa");
    int answer = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        answer++;
    }
    System.out.println(answer == N);
```

Если нужно решить задачу без циклов, составьте сразу регeлярное выражение, которое проверит N вхождений

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a.*a.*a.*");
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("a.*a.*a.*a.*");

Matcher matcher = p.matcher("abcdaa");
Matcher matcher1 = p1.matcher("abcdaa");
if(matcher.find() && !matcher1.find()){
   System.out.println("YES");
} else {
   System.out.println("NO");
}
```

Где в первом паттертне строка повторяется N раз, а во втором N+1

Comment: Спасибо, Иван Гладуш. А можно решить эту задачу без циклов?

Comment: Да, но это будет не оптимально по времени работы приложения

Comment: @Bakuard, добавил код и без цикла

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
String text = "asdadaaaas";
String pattern = "a";
int result = text.split( pattern ).length - 1;
System.out.println( result );
```

https://ideone.com/4QkPSL